# JetBrains DataGrip: The left toolbar is not displayed

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I can move an area to the left toolbar.
While the icon is being dragged, the toolbar is shown, but after that the toolbar is hidden.
How to make the toolbar always visible, like in Rider or WebStorm.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Do you have the toolbar with button on the top? Like this one: https://imgur.com/uGh8yLo

Answer (score 1):

If the toolbar is not shown, please ensure you have **Show tool window toolbar** checkbox enabled in **File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance**